# How to raise an event click, have fields added to Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have code that works correctly

```
$(document).on('click',"a.img,a.imgs",function() {
    $(this).next().find('a:first').click();
    return false;
});
```

But when I add new fields ajax ( for example show more), then with them this code does not work, and it's sad

Comment: Do you add the img class on your link when you add new fields via ajax?

Comment: "and it's sad", I laughed hard. Make sure your added code complies to the selectors you're using in your event registrator. Also, encapsulate the event in a function, and run it again each time you add elements.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer as I misread your code and got everything mixed up.

Here's an explanation from another SO thread that might help you fix the problem:

> It's probably not working due to one of:
>
> - Not using recent version of jQuery
> - **Not wrapping your code inside of DOM ready**
> - or you are doing something    which causes the event not to bubble up to the listener on the    document.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This WILL work because we are listening on the 'document', 
    // for a click on an element with an ID of #test-element
    $(document).on("click","#test-element",function() {
        alert("click bound to document listening for #test-element");
    });

    // This will NOT work because there is no '#test-element' ... yet
    $("#test-element").on("click",function() {
        alert("click bound directly to #test-element");
    });

    // Create the dynamic element '#test-element'
    $('body').append('<div id="test-element">Click mee</div>');
});
```

[$(document).on("click"... not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605296/document-onclick-not-working)