# .on() event handler not firing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {

          $(document).on('click', 'th.default', function() {
            alert("hello world!");
          });

          $(document).on('click', '#columnHeaders', function()
          {
              alert('Hello world!');
          });

          /*$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
           var target = $(e.target);
           if (target.is('.default')) {
              e.preventDefault(); // if you want to cancel the event flow
              // do something
              alert('Hello world!');
           } else if (target.is('.myotherclass')) {
              e.preventDefault();
              // do something else
              alert('Nah');
           }
        });*/
      });

      /*var theParent = document.querySelector("#columnHeaders");
      theParent.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);

      function doSomething(e) {
          if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
              var clickedItem = e.target.id;
              alert("Hello " + clickedItem);
          }
          e.stopPropagation();
      }*/
      //on click: show textbox, hide label

      function renameColumn(label_id)
      {
        alert('Entered rename' label_id);
        //change 'Rename' to 'Save'
        var elt = document.getElementById(label_id);
        if (elt.nodeName == "LABEL")
        {
          document.getElementById(label_id).innerHTML = 'Save';
          $(label_id).css('display', 'none');
        }

        var elt = document.getElementById(inputText_id)
        if (elt.nodeName == "INPUT")
        {
          $(inputText_id)
          .val($(label_id).text())
          .css('display','')
          .focus();
        }
      }

      //on blur
      function cancelRename(editText, column_id)
      {
        document.getElementById(label).innerHTML = 'Rename';
        $(editText).css('display', 'none');
        $(column_id)
        .css('display', '');
      }

      //on save
      function saveColumnName(label)
      {
        document.getElementById(label).innerHTML = 'Rename';
      }
  </script>
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="jQuery Kanban Widget with Multiple Kanbans" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css"); ?>">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js");?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js");?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/jqwidgets/jqxsortable.js");?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/jqwidgets/jqxkanban.js");?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/scripts/demos.js");?>"></script>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/dashboard/reset">Reset</a>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?/dashboard/insertNewColumn/1/0">Add Column</a>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?/dashboard/insertNewRow/1">Add Row</a>
    <?php
      $levels = $columnData[0];
      $maxrowspan = $columnData[1];
      $max_parent_colspan = 0;
      $num_rows = $rowData[1];
      $rows = $rowData[0];
      $td_var = '';
      $default_column = false;

?>

<?php
      echo "<table id=\"columnHeaders\" border=1 style='font-family: Arial; font-size:13' layout=auto>";
      foreach ($levels as $level_id => $level_array) 
      {
        echo "<tr>";
        if (!$default_column)
        {
          echo "<th rowspan=".($maxrowspan+1)." class='default'>Default</th>";
          $default_column = true;
        }

        if ($level_id > 1)
        {
          foreach ($level_array as $child_column_id => $array_properties) 
          {
            $colspan = $array_properties['child_colspan'];
            $is_parent = $array_properties['has_child'];

            if ($colspan == 1 && !$is_parent) 
            {
              foreach ($level_array as $id => $array_props)
              {
                $cols = $array_props['child_colspan'];
                $is_p = $array_props['has_child'];
                $td_var = "<td>

                <label id=\"col_{$child_column_id}\">{$child_column_id}</label>

                <input type=\"text\" id=\"text_{$child_column_id}\" style=\"display:none\">

                 <br>
                 <span id=\"{$child_column_id}\" class=\"rename\">Rename</span> /

                 <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/deleteCol/{$child_column_id}\"> Delete</a> /

                 <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/insertNewColumn/1/{$child_column_id}\">Split</a>

                 </td>";

                if ($cols > 0 && $id != $child_column_id && $is_p) 
                {
                  $td_var = "<td rowspan={$maxrowspan}> <label id={$child_column_id}>{$child_column_id}</label><br> Rename / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/deleteCol/{$child_column_id}\"> Delete</a> / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/insertNewColumn/1/{$child_column_id}\">Split</a> </td>";
                  break;
                }
              }
            } else {
              $td_var = "<td colspan={$colspan}> <label id={$child_column_id}>{$child_column_id}</label> <br> Rename / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/deleteCol/{$child_column_id}\"> Delete</a> / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/insertNewColumn/1/{$child_column_id}\">Split</a> </td>";
            }
            echo $td_var;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          foreach($level_array as $level1_parent_col_id => $parent_properties)
          {
            $colspan = $parent_properties['colspan'];
            if ($parent_properties['num_of_children'] > 0)
            {
              echo "<th colspan = {$colspan}> <label id={$level1_parent_col_id}>{$level1_parent_col_id}</label> <br> Rename / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/deleteCol/{$level1_parent_col_id}\"> Delete</a> / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/insertNewColumn/1/{$level1_parent_col_id}\">Split</a> </th>";
            } else {
              echo "<th rowspan = ".(++$maxrowspan)."><label id={$level1_parent_col_id}>{$level1_parent_col_id}</label> <br> Rename / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/deleteCol/{$level1_parent_col_id}\"> Delete</a> / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/insertNewColumn/1/{$level1_parent_col_id}\">Split</a> </th>";
            }
            $max_parent_colspan += $colspan;
          }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
     ?>

     <table border=1>
     <?php

     foreach($rows as $r)
     {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>  <br> Rename / <a href=\"".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/deleteRow/{$r->id}\"> Delete</a> </td>";

       for ($y = 0; $y < $max_parent_colspan; $y++)
       {
         echo "<td> Row {$y} </td>";
       }

       echo "</tr>";
     }
      ?>
     </table>

<br />
  </div>
```

I'm trying to bind multiple elements to a single event listener. I tried it first for a single element, the `th.default`, but the event never fires.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'th.default', function() {
            alert("hello world!");
    });
});

<?php
      //not inside a <div> nor <body>
      echo "<table id=\"columnHeaders\" border=1 style='font-family: Arial; font-size:13' layout=auto>";
      foreach ($levels as $level_id => $level_array) //Loop through each level
      {
        echo "<tr>";
        if (!$default_column)
        {
          echo "<th rowspan=".($maxrowspan+1)." class=\"default\">Default</td>";
          $default_column = true;
        }
         //More cells below
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting error in console? Your code should work

Comment: Can you try `'.default'` instead of `'th.default'` ?

Comment: try using class='default' instead of class=\"default\"

Comment: @Satpal no errors.

Comment: @herondale what is the version of jquery you are using?

Comment: @vvtx I just did, still no alert message

Comment: @DavidR I did, no alert message firing

Comment: Using element inspector, check to see if the markup looks OK, and (at least in firefox) that you have a symbol (ev) next to a `th` with class `default`

Comment: @herondale It really seems that you are getting some error at your browser's console.

Comment: the fact that in the question the javascript is outside of `<?php ...?>` block but **not** inside a `<script>` block looks suspicious. Sure, it's probably minimal code, but it looks, in the question, to be a single file - and there's not even any reason to believe you're loading jQuery at all, or correctly

Comment: nah, was just saying the code looked wrong - but I understand minimal examples can be odd looking

Comment: @JaromandaX and i'm not quite sure what you meant by the symbol next to a `th`?

Comment: if you use firefox developer tools inspector you'll see **ev** next to elements with an event handler

Comment: @JaromandaX hmm, on firebug it says *There are no event listeners directly on this element.*

Comment: yeah, I don't know firebug - built in debugger is far less rubbish than firebug

Comment: @JaromandaX i updated my question with new code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 'on' works relative to elements you have to give a exist element to listen event, such as 'body' which always it exist on page .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', 'th.default', function(event) {
            alert("hello world!");
    });
});
```

this seems duplicate please look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605296/document-onclick-not-working) [$(document).on("click"... not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605296/document-onclick-not-working)

Comment: any issue with `$(document)`?

Comment: and what/how come is that?

Comment: please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605296/document-onclick-not-working

Answer (score 1):

As i can see you are generating your markup through php, so event delegation is not required in your case because markup generation is done at server and this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('th.default').on('click', function() {
         alert("hello world!");
    });
});
```

Also you have to ensure you are using correct version of jQuery which has the `.on()` event listener as earlier versions from `1.7` don't have.

---

#### *Additional*

You have to put jquery library just before the script you are trying to execute.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   // Here you should put your script.
</script>
```

Comment: If he's using the wrong jquery version he'll get an error in the Javascript console. But he hasn't yet answered the question of whether he's getting an error.

Comment: True! expected...!

Comment: I did include the jquery library. I also tried this: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` doesnt seem to work either. I'll try to see if firebug has something

Comment: @herondale as per `jquery 3.x.x` `$(document).ready()` method is i guess removed. Instead use the preferred version as `$(function(){ // code here in this ready block })`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'th.default', function() {
            alert("hello world!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="columnHeaders" border=1 style='font-family: Arial; font-size:13' layout=auto>
  <tr><th class="default">Default</th><th class="default">Default</th><th class="default">Default</th></tr>
</table>
```

One issue that may be causing your problem is that the closing `</td>` tags are incorrect and should be `</th>`. If the browser is correcting the opening tags to `<td>` then your event will not fire.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i didn't see that. I have corrected it but I'm still not getting the alert

Comment: Can you update your question with a working example of your code in a code snippet?

Comment: it's connected to the database, so it will surely throw errors. will that be okay?

Comment: Thanks, please replace the PHP code in your snippet with the HTML that this outputs on your local machine so that it can actually be tested.