# Changing HTML5 video src dynamically on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, video

I have the following code which loads a local video on an Android device and places it in a HTML5 Video src tag:

**Javascript code:**

```
var path = 'file:///data/data/com.myapp.app/files/';

var src = path+'Intro.mp4';
var video = $("#introVideo");

video.find("source").attr("src", src);
```

**HTML code:**

```
<video id="introVideo" width="100%" poster="poster.jpg"controls>
<source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This doesn't work on Android device. However, if i don't use the javascript code above and just use the video path like the following, everything works fine:

**This works:**

```
<video id="introVideo" width="100%" poster="poster.jpg"controls>
<source src="file:///data/data/com.myapp.app/files/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

When i `alert(src);` I get the exact URL which is:

```
file:///data/data/com.myapp.app/files/Intro.mp4
```

Which means the video exist locally and there is an issue with my Javascript code above. But i don't understand what the issue is!

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is how the code above is trigerred:

```
$(document).on('click','.backit', function(e){

    var path = 'file:///data/data/com.myapp.app/files/';

    var src = path+'Intro.mp4';
    var video = $("#introVideo");

    video.find("source").attr("src", src);

});
```

**EDIT:**

Further investigation, I found out that the Video's src tag is being set correctly when i use my javascript code above, However, the video doesn't play when i set its src tag dynamically which is very strange.

Comment: is your js in a `ready` block or placed under your html, to ensure that it is not running until the html is rendered?

Comment: @chiliNUT, the javascript above will be only triggered on a button click and the button is only available long after the html rendering is complete.

Comment: well then maybe you could provide a more complete code sample

Comment: @chiliNUT, that is all the code i have... the only difference is I didn't wrap it around the $(document).on('click','.backit', function(e){......});

Comment: same question as before then, are you binding the click event to `.backit` before its rendered

Comment: @chiliNUT, yea, indeed. because I do the alert(src); inside the click function and it works fine.

Comment: nvm and also ur binding to document. id make sure you have the class name right and then maybe this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605296/document-onclick-not-working, also for android it helps to have a remote console for seeing js errors

Comment: have you checked that all the assets (not just the hardcoded one) are being bundled in the source/transferred to the device?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, yeah, since this is a hybrid type of a project, i tested the same code on an iOS device and it works fine. But Android seems to dislike my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what framework you're using, I just did a quick test for a similar scenario using an existing bare-bones Android app that loads an HTML page, and this worked for me (note that at runtime my webview is accessing assets from the `file:///android_asset/` path as my videos are local to the project):

HTML

```
<video id="vid" width="320" height="240"></video>
```

Initial JS:

```
var path = 'file:///android_asset/';
var vid = document.getElementById('vid');
var src = document.createElement('source');

src.setAttribute('src', path + 'video1.mp4');

vid.appendChild(src);
vid.play();
```

to change the source to a new video

```
src.setAttribute('src', path + 'video2.mp4'); 

vid.load();
vid.play();
```