# jQuery on click does not work but a "standard" click event does

Tags: jquery

So I have the following:

**Does not work**

```
$(document).on('click','#memberships_save', function(){
```

**Does work**

```
$('#memberships_save').click(function() {
```

The element is not dynamically created. The on method works in other triggers on the page, just not for this specific ID. The ID exists only once in the HTML.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605296/document-onclick-not-working

Comment: Unfortunately not - I read that before posting

Answer (score 0):

Both methods work for me: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/wvGgJdR)

Could it be that `disabled=true` prevents the first method from working? You could use a class to mimic the appearance of a disabled button instead.